# JSON Data parsing - how to?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to parse JSON data but I am not getting expected results as wanted. I have tried many solutions on StackOverflow but not getting it fixed.

This is the JSON response

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Get all provinces",
    "data": {
        "provinces": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "user_id": 16,
                "name": "Sindh",
                "code": "Sindh",
                "population": 47890000,
                "geo_data": null,
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2019-05-03 16:04:31",
                "updated_at": "2019-05-03 16:04:31",
                "verified": "0",
                "verified_by": null,
                "verified_at": null
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "user_id": 16,
                "name": "Punjab",
                "code": "Punjab",
                "population": 110012442,
                "geo_data": null,
                "status": "1",
                "created_at": "2019-05-03 16:13:14",
                "updated_at": "2019-05-03 16:13:14",
                "verified": "0",
                "verified_by": null,
                "verified_at": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is how I am creating an API interface to call the endpoint:

```
@GET("geography/get-provinces")
fun getAllProvinces(
    @Header("api_token") api_token: String
):Call<ProvinceResponseModel>
```

this is my model Class

```
data class ProvinceResponseModel(
    val `data`: ProvinceData,
    val message: String,
    val status: Int
)

data class Province(
    val code: String,
    val created_at: String,
    val geo_data: Any,
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val population: Int,
    val status: String,
    val updated_at: String,
    val user_id: Int,
    val verified: String,
    val verified_at: Any,
    val verified_by: Any
)

data class ProvinceData(
    val provinces: List<Province>
)
```

This is how I am calling API

```
private fun loadProvinceList() {
    progressbarr.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val apiService = ApiClient.client.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    val listcall = apiService.getAllProvinces(
        Constants.API.API_TOKEN
    )

    listcall.enqueue(object : Callback<ProvinceResponseModel> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProvinceResponseModel>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            progressbarr.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ProvinceResponseModel>, response: Response<ProvinceResponseModel>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                progressbarr.visibility = View.GONE
                val provinceListResults: ProvinceData = response.body()!!.data
                val results: List<Province> = provinceListResults.provinces
                provinceList.clear()
                for (i in results.indices){
                    val province = results[i]
                    provinceList.add(province)
                    Log.d(TAG, results[i].id.toString())
                }
                loadProvinceData()
            } else {
                progressbarr.visibility = View.GONE
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, "Login Error Please try again: $response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
        }

    })
}
```

I am getting a response in this format

```
Province(code=Sindh, created_at=2019-05-03 16:04:31, geo_data=null, id=4, name=Sindh, population=47890000, status=1, updated_at=2019-05-03 16:04:31, user_id=16, verified=0, verified_at=null, verified_by=null)
```

but I want to remove this Province() and want to get individual attributes.

Comment: this may helps you. http://divine4android.blogspot.com/2019/07/android-json-response-parsing-method.html

Comment: There is not any issue in your code, you are getting the result in expected format and where `Province` is just a class name and it's getting logged as you are using `data class` which has toString method by default.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is using default `toString()` and that's why you are getting that format. If we wish to get a different format in your Province data class override toString() function to return the format you want:

```
data class Something(
    val a: String,
    val b: Any,
    val c: String
) {
    override fun toString(): String = a + b + c
}
```